# Selenium webdriver with Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I need help to fetch the value from a tag. Below is the element and its `xpath`

element:

```
<a href="/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=37129112">Sprint1 AC/AT's</a>
```

`xpath`:

```
.//*[@id='content']/div[5]/ul/li/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a
```

code:

```
sprint="Sprint1"

if sprint in (browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[5]/ul/li/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/a")):
    print ("Wow")
else:
    print ("NotWow")
```

`print xpath` returns:

```
selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="f680d2ed-7f35-46b2-9f75-c5f27095e39b", element="d5b83487-a476-4a00-b470-37668636bdd4")
```

Can you please help me with the string comparison with the webelement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to get single `webelement` you should use `find_element_...()` instead of `find_elements_...()`
2. If you need to get link text you should use `text` property of `webelement`:

   ```
   sprint="Sprint1"

   if sprint in browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='content']/div[5]/ul/li/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[2]/a").text:
       print ("Wow")
   else:
       print ("NotWow")
   ```